# Python: How can we initiate an empty list and add new elements with names?

Tags: python, list

I would like to initiate a list (or other data type?) and add new numerical data into the list. Then I would like to be able to call each data point by name. My data looks like:

```
Alice 4
Bob 7
John 3
....
```

Let us call the list I establish `ls1`. The results I hope are: 
`ls1["Alice"]`will give me `4`, and `ls1["Bob"]`will give me `7`, etc.

How can I do it? Thank you!!

Comment: What you want is a dictionary not list.

Comment: @SayandipDutta How should I do it?

Comment: That is an inappropriate question for Stack Overflow.  Please repeat the intro tour, especially [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).  there are many available resources already on line to teach you how to use basic Python language features; Stack Overflow is not intended to replace those.

Answer (score 2):

Use dictionary for this:

```
ls1 = {
  "Alice": "4",
  "Bob": "7",
  "John": 4
}
print(ls1["Alice"])
```

[documentation for dictionaries](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries)

Comment: Please do not answer off-topic questions.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `dict` instead of `list`.

Code example:

```
a = dict()

a["Alice"] = 4
a["Bob"] = 7
a["John"] = 3

print(a["Alice"])
```

Answer (score 1):

You might be looking for a dictionary here.

To initiate a dictionary -

```
sampledict =    {
      "Alice": 4,
      "Bob": 7,
      "John": 3
    }
```

You can now access each element by the name i.e. `sampledict["Alice"]`